# What is the [packages] tag useful for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burnination-request

We have [.deb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/.deb) or was [deb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/deb), well, we have that. We have [package-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package-management) as well. Why do we need yet-another-tag without someone that can be actually be an expert of all aspect of the "packages" topic?

Is it useful for something? Can be alone in a question which another tag isn't more fitting?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think we can safely roll [packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packages) into [package-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package-management).

There are probably a few exceptions but I don't think there are many questions where package-management wouldn't apply. [To the wider meta audience] let me know if that sounds desirable or not and we'll make it happen.